# Aligning awkward plot and axis titles

Tags: r, plot

I have created the following plot showing changes in temperatures (left column) and changes in precipitation (right column) from 1979-2015 for each of the 4 seasons (each row):

[image]

I now wish to add a common y-axis label to the 4 plots on the left side of the plot called "Temperatures (°C)" and the same on the right side of the plot called "Precipitation (mm)". I also wish to have a centre-aligned title for each row of plots with the names of the seasons. The output should look like:

[image]

I have looked at various examples of plotting with invisible plots to create axis titles etc. but cannot adapt any of this to my situation. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Sorry @ZheyuanLi, I was on holiday and had not checked this again until now. This works great and is a fantastic help - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment 5 hours ago, there is a way to settle all positioning, by using `mtext()`; it is just that I don't know whether this is the best solution. However, there has been 5 hours and no answer arrives, so I decide to post mine.

There is no difficulty in placing "Temperatures", "Precipitations" and "Winter", but it requires some tuning on placing "Spring", "Summer" and "Autumn". The variable `offset` in the following **template code** controls such tuning. `offset = -14.5` is near-optimal, when I produce the figure on:

```
jpeg(file = "template.jpeg", width = 600, height = 600, quality = 100)
## template code
dev.off()
```

Depending on the size of your plot, you need to adjust / reset `offset` by your needs.

---

**Template Code**

```
## set plot layout, inner margin and outer margin
par(mfrow=c(4,2), mar = c(1.5,2.5,1.5,2.5), oma = c(3,4,3,4))

## plot 1
plot(1:5, ann = FALSE, xaxt = "n")
axis(4, at = axTicks(4))
axis(1, at = axTicks(1), labels= NA)

## plot 2
plot(1:5, ann = FALSE, xaxt = "n")
axis(4, at = axTicks(4))
axis(1, at = axTicks(1), labels= NA)

## plot 3
plot(1:5, ann = FALSE, xaxt = "n")
axis(4, at = axTicks(4))
axis(1, at = axTicks(1), labels= NA)

## plot 4
plot(1:5, ann = FALSE, xaxt = "n")
axis(4, at = axTicks(4))
axis(1, at = axTicks(1), labels= NA)

## plot 5
plot(1:5, ann = FALSE, xaxt = "n")
axis(4, at = axTicks(4))
axis(1, at = axTicks(1), labels= NA)

## plot 6
plot(1:5, ann = FALSE, xaxt = "n")
axis(4, at = axTicks(4))
axis(1, at = axTicks(1), labels= NA)

## plot 7
plot(1:5, ann = FALSE)
axis(4, at = axTicks(4))

## plot 8
plot(1:5, ann = FALSE)
axis(4, at = axTicks(4))

## write text on outer margins
mtext("Temperatures (°C)", 2, outer = TRUE, line = 2, font = 2)
mtext("Precipitation (mm)", 4, outer = TRUE, line = 2, font = 2)
mtext("Winter", 3, outer = TRUE, line = 0, font = 2)

## needs tuning on `offset`
offset <- -14.5
mtext("Spring", 3, outer = TRUE, line = offset, font = 2)
mtext("Summer", 3, outer = TRUE, line = 2 * offset, font = 2)
mtext("Autumn", 3, outer = TRUE, line = 3 * offset, font = 2)
```

[image]